# Convert OR to beta and find standard errors from confidence interval

Tags: odds-ratio, beta-distribution

I have an OR for 1.9 unit change in a height, with 95%CI 1.05(1.02 - 1.07).
I want to convert this OR to beta and get the standard error. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear to people who don't already know what you're asking about... what is an OR?  What is a beta?

Comment: OR is probably odds ratio.  I am not sure what beta refers to.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to confirm that OR=odds-ratio (which  is a tag you have used). The regression coefficients have nothing to do with the beta-distribution so you might want to remove that tag. You might consider adding the tag for logistic regression if that is what you used.

Comment: beta will be the parameter estimate, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. I was referring beta = logistic coefficient, OR = Odds ratio.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you mean $\beta$ = regression coefficient on the logit scale and OR = odds ratio, then the following works: take the inverse logit ($\exp (x)/(1+\exp (x))$) of the estimate and confidence limits to get the $\beta$ with 95% CI. The standard error is then approximately the CI width divided by $2 \times 1.95996$.

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear to me. What is x, is it the Odds Ratio? Isn't it true that OR = exp(Beta)? So its just OR = ln(Beta)

Comment: @emschorsch the statements that they have written above can be rewritten to be equivalent to e^B.  
Please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#The_odds_ratio